# Laravel jrenton/laravel-scaffold

Tags: laravel, scaffolding

I am starting to use laravel and i am having problems with **jrenton/laravel-scaffold** library.
When i use its scaffold it generates everything, but the controllers are empty files.
I`m generating from a file shown in the github page of the library:

```
resource = true
namespace = Oxford
University hasMany Department string( name city state homepage ) -nt
Department belongsTo University, hasMany Course string( name description ) number:integer
resource = false
Course belongsTo Department, hasMany Lesson string( name description ) integer( number credits ) -sd
```

If you need more information ask in the comment section.

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the controller? The HTTP verb methods? (if that's what they're called? index, add, edit, delete etc.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate you're problem

Answer (score 1):

There's a template folder that contains Controller and View templates to use with the scaffolding. Check under the 'resource' and 'restful' folders for them at: https://github.com/jrenton/laravel-scaffold/tree/master/src/Jrenton/LaravelScaffold/templates

Comment: At that link go into the restful directory and use controller.txt.  You can copy that contents or rename it. example: ArticlesController.php